# I am getting this error "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." on mvc app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl

Below web config code

```
  <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false"/>
        <machineKey validationKey="FF4636C4DF933BE453F9B94810661C5F5625794E5DCA46A3C281EB18CC5410386A4B38F5E4C7D7106C049C9EB10F31C2F4E76E74616ABD36DC6C64AF2BFF6801" decryptionKey="667F9049734567FF3E7BC7031DF4B4431F992A447CE2FB3258F6EE989BA82E8F" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
        <httpHandlers>
          <add path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
          <add path="*" verb="TRACE" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
          <add path="*" verb="HEAD" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <authorization>
          <deny verbs="OPTIONS" users="*"/>
          <deny verbs="TRACE" users="*"/>
          <deny verbs="HEAD" users="*"/>
        </authorization>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Home" name="testdb" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
        </authentication>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
        <sessionState timeout="20"/>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/ErrorPage"/>
      </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"/>
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      </system.webServer>
```

When i published code.I got this message "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." on error log.But when i set requireSSL="false" in web config it's working Properly.but in security tool it shows vulnerabiltiy.

Please help!

Comment: after login to my application,it suddenly logged out and below error message appears "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: yeah, we get that. the reason for this is most likely that there was no valid certificate for an SSL connection on the server. either allow your application to ignore invalid certificates (or lack of certificates), or install a valid certificate.